# Linear algebra, power of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$P^{-1}AP =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} 
$
with 
$P= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
and $P^{-1}$ is the inverse of $P$

Find $A$, $A^{100}$?

I found $A$, $P^{-1}AP=B$ and multiplied by $P$ and $P^{-1}$. How can I find $A^{100}$? I have to use eigenvalues/vectors.

Comment: To find A^100 you have to compute the eigenvalues decomposition of $A$ and then take the 100-th power of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @ABC he already has the "eigenvalue decomposition" :-)

Answer (score 6):

You've told us that you know $A$, so I'm assuming that this is the case.

Here's a general formula for finding $A^n$:

$A^n=\underbrace{(PB\overbrace{P^{-1})(P}^{I}B\overbrace{P^{-1})(P}^{I}B\overbrace{P^{-1})P}^{I}...\overbrace{P^{-1}(P}^{I}B\overbrace{P^{-1})(P}^{I}BP^{-1})}_{n \ \text{times}}$.

Simplifying this, we see that:
$$\boxed{A^n=PB^nP^{-1}},$$ where $B$ is (diagonal) matrix of eigenvalues,and $P=[\vec r_1 \cdots\vec r_n]$ is the matrix of eigenvectors.

Subbing $n=100$ into this formula, we have:
$$A^{100}=PB^{100}P^{-1}.$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Huh?  $B$ is *not* diagonal, so how is one supposed to compute $B^{100}$?  The only way I see is to use the Jordan decomposition as in user1551's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $B=P^{-1}AP=(-I_3+N)\oplus2$. Therefore $B^{100}=P^{-1}A^{100}P=(-I_3+N)^{100}\oplus2^{100}$. Since $N^3=0$, by binomial theorem,
$$(-I+N)^{100}=(-I)^{100}+\binom{100}1(-I)^{99}N+\binom{100}2(-I)^{98}N^2.$$

Comment: This is a lot simpler than induction. I've never drawn this connection before. +1 for simplifying my future computations.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way that $P$ and $A$ are constructed, it is not hard to see that $PA=AP$. Consequently, $P^{-1}AP=P^{-1}PA=A$. So that makes life easier. You can then write
$$
          A = 
     \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
          -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 2
          \end{array}\right]+
    \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
           0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0
          \end{array}\right] = D+N,
$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix and $N$ is nilpotent of order $3$ (meaning that $N^{3}=0$, but $N^{2} \ne 0$.) You have $DN=ND=-N$ and
$$
        N^{2} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
           0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 0
          \end{array}\right],\;\;\; N^{3}=0.
$$
This is how the Jordan canonical form works. $N$ works on the same part of the space corresponding to the columns with $-1$ entries. So $DN=ND=-N$. And $DN^{2}=N^{2}D=-N^{2}$. So,
$$
(D+N)^{100} = D^{100}+(100)D^{99}N+(50)(99)D^{98}N^{2}=D^{100}-100N+50(99)N^{2}.
$$
You can write down the matrix $A^{100}$ from this. Nothing further is needed.

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of suspect that the point of this question is that $P$ and $P^{-1}$ diagonalise $B$. In the case of a diagonalised matrix,D, $D^{100}$ just means taking each element to the power of 100, since each multiplication just multiplies each diagonal element by itself. It is often the fastest way to take large powers of matrixes. First diagonalise, then note the trick by alex that $A^n = PB^nP^{-1}$ with B diagonal.